# Sphider for vertical search angine

Tags: search-engine, sphider

I'm investigating different tools for building a vertical search engine. I've come across http://www.sphider.eu/ and I think it works fine.

However, I'm not sure how many pages it can index. There seems to be no information about this in the documentatation. I think I will index around hundred sites for this particular search engine and I will have to reindex them at least once a day.

Can Sphider manage this? Or should I look for other solutions?

Comment: I have never used it, but you should verify if it polls multiple pages in parallel. Network latency will be the biggest bottleneck. If it does multiple requests in parallel, it should do as good as any other crawler out there.